# How I can hide a user from the login screen?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-accounts, login, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu 9.04 and I want to hide a user from appearing in the Login Screen, I shouldn't remove it permanently of course, but I need to make it visible again when needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
System Settings > Advanced > System > Login Manager > Users
```

Select the check-boxes of the users you want to hide.

Comment: all right, but I would like to know if there is a command line (UNIX) that do the same job (as a real power user)

Answer (score 2):

In Debian-based systems (which includes Ubuntu and Kubuntu, both versions new and old), any user with a UID less than 1000 will not show up as a user you can log in with, but you can still use the user from the command line with things such as ssh and ftp.

So to make the user `bob` disappear from the login screen, run the following command (`800` can be any value less than `1000`, but I like starting in that range):

```
$ sudo usermod -u 800 bob
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me on Ubuntu 20.10 running Gnome desktop v3.38.1 , unless I also need to set group ID / groups? (still looking for a way to do it, trying things listed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2471/how-to-hide-users-from-the-gdm-login-screen )

Answer (score 1):

Posting for those reading this in the future.

Using Ubuntu 22.04, I have used the following guide:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-login-screen

TL:DR:

If your system uses `AccountsService`, you can not hide a user from the greeter screen by reconfiguring `lightdm` (and potentially other dms) because it defers to `AccountsService`. That is stated very clearly in the comments in `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`.

1. `vim /var/lib/AccountsService/users/XXX` where `XXX` is the username.
2. add this line or change `SystemAccount=` from `false` to `true`, if it already exists.

```
[User]
SystemAccount=true
```

3. `sudo systemctl restart accounts-daemon.service`